# Why is my lock not blocking?

Tags: c#, multithreading

It seems that lock isn't working in my code below.

Here's some background on what I am trying to do:

I have an inventory management system that does the following:

1. receive orders
2. allocate existing inventory to fulfill orders
3. if unable to fill an order, flag order as backordered
4. attempt to fill backorders whenever new inventory is added
5. allow for cancellation of an order.

So let's say 100 orders are on backorder, then a shipment of inventory comes in that can fill all 100 backorders. When the shipment is received by my Warehousing class (not shown below), the AllocateOutstandingRequests method defined below is called. Eventually we end up in the first foreach loop of my AllocateInventory method below, which iterates thru the 100 orders, trying to allocate inventory for each. Now, let's say that loop is on item 80 when my Messaging class (partially defined below) receives a CancelOrder for order number 2 of that list. The CancelOrder routine calls my AddCancel routine in the Allocation class, and SHOULD block on lock (_cancelsLock), but it does not. I have tracing all over this code with timestamps and threadId, AND I even put a 3 second delay in the loop that attempts to allocate inventory for the backordered items. I can see in the trace that the loop works exactly as expected, with 3 seconds between each allocation, but I can also see that the AddCancel call returns immediately back to my Messaging class with no delay; I expected a delay, it should block until all 100 orders have been allocated and the lock released. What am I doing wrong? Seems the lock in AddCancel does not do anything at all !

I've added what logging looks like, both in the code, and the actual log entries from the log file. As can be seen, Messaging.ReceiveInventory [threadId 38] receives inventory and calls Allocation.AllocateOutstandingRequests, which in turn starts up the task [threadId 26]:

2014-02-28 17:00:08,871 [38] INFO  - Processing incoming ReceiveDrugs request by User:WELLDYNERX\privera

2014-02-28 17:00:08,871 [38] INFO  - NDC 00002323230 added to inventory for requestor 110

2014-02-28 17:00:08,871 [26] INFO  - ...Allocating outstanding requests

2014-02-28 17:00:08,887 [26] INFO  - Attempting to allocate 100 outstanding requests

2014-02-28 17:00:08,934 [26] INFO  - Backordered RequestUID 100689 Allocated

2014-02-28 17:00:23,934 [26] INFO  - Backordered RequestUID 100690 Allocated

2014-02-28 17:00:25,293 [42] INFO  - Processing incoming CancelNotification; UID:100689, from PRIVERA for RequestorUID:110

2014-02-28 17:00:25,309 [42] INFO  - CancelNotification for UID:100689, processed.

2014-02-28 17:00:39,012 [26] INFO  - Backordered RequestUID 100691 Allocated

2014-02-28 17:00:54,012 [26] INFO  - Backordered RequestUID 100692 Allocated

Allocation Class:

```
public static class Allocation
{
    public static void AllocateOutstandingRequests()
    {
        var factory = new TaskFactory(_orderedTaskScheduler);
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += OrderedTaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

        factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("...Allocating outstanding requests");
            List<QueueingRequest> backorderedRequests = InventoryDao.GetBackorderedRequests();
            List<AllocationRequest> backorderedRequestsAllocated =
                AllocateInventory(backorderedRequests.OrderBy(r => r.RequestUID).ToList());
            SendAllocationResponses(backorderedRequestsAllocated);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Completed allocating outstanding requests...");
        });  
    }

    static List<AllocationRequest> AllocateInventory(List<QueueingRequest> outstandingRequests)
    {
        List<AllocationRequest> allocatedBackorderedRequests = new List<AllocationRequest>();

        lock (_cancelsLock)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Attempting to allocate {0} outstanding requests", outstandingRequests.Count));

            foreach (QueueingRequest queuedRequest in outstandingRequests)
            {
                if (_cancels.Contains(queuedRequest.RequestUID)) continue;

                AllocationRequest allocationRequest = new AllocationRequest(queuedRequest);
                if (AllocateOrder(allocationRequest))
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Backordered RequestUID {0} Allocated", queuedRequest.RequestUID));
                    allocatedBackorderedRequests.Add(allocationRequest);
                }

                for (int iSleepAlot = 0; iSleepAlot < 5; iSleepAlot++)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }

            // Check to see if a CancelOrder came thru for backordered requests 
            // that the code above allocated inventory for.
            foreach (int requestUID in allocatedBackorderedRequests.Select(r => r.RequestUID))
            {
                if (_cancels.Contains(requestUID))
                    _cancels.Remove(requestUID);
            }
        }

        return allocatedBackorderedRequests;
    }

    static bool AllocateOrder(AllocationRequest request)
    {
        bool inventoryAllocated = false;

        try
        {
            if (InventoryDao.SaveAllocation(request))
                inventoryAllocated = Warehousing.AllocateDrugs(request.RequestorUID, request.Items);
        }
        catch (RequestAlreadyAllocatedException ex)
        {
            inventoryAllocated = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }

        return inventoryAllocated;
    }

    public static bool AddCancel(int requestUID)
    {
        bool requestStatusChangedToAllocated = false;
        _cancels.Add(requestUID);

        // block until backordered requests are allocated.
        lock (_cancelsLock)
        {
            requestStatusChangedToAllocated = !_cancels.Contains(requestUID);

            if (!requestStatusChangedToAllocated)
                _cancels.Remove(requestUID);
        }

        return requestStatusChangedToAllocated;
    }

    static readonly TaskScheduler _orderedTaskScheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);
    static readonly List<int> _cancels = new List<int>();
    static readonly object _cancelsLock = new object();
}
```

Messaging Class:

```
public static class Messaging
{
    public static void CancelOrder(CancelNotification notification)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Processing incoming CancelNotification; UID:{0}, from {1} for RequestorUID:{2}",
                                                 notification.RequestUID,
                                                 notification.User,
                                                 notification.RequestorUID));
        // This is a blocking call which returns after all backordered requests are processed.
        // The call may change the status from backordered to allocated, in which case, we'll
        // have to DeAllocateDrugs in the services cache
        bool requestStatusChangedToAllocated = Allocation.AddCancel(notification.RequestUID);

        // do some work

        Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("CancelNotification for UID:{0}, processed.", notification.RequestUID));
    }

    public static List<string> ReceiveInventory(List<ReceivedInventory> received, string user, string comment)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Processing incoming ReceiveDrugs request by User:{0}", user));

        foreach (ReceivedInventory inventory in received)
        {
            // do some work
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("NDC {0} added to inventory for requestor {1}", drugInventory.NDC, inventory.RequestorUID));
        }

        // re-evaluate allocations after inventory is loaded
        Allocation.AllocateOutstandingRequests();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally - bad style. Use your own task scheduler and use 1 task at a time - WAY more efficient than locking when you get a ton of orders. Serial processing in a messaging environment is much better serverd making sure there only is one worker working on the messages.

Comment: when/where is AllocateOutstandingRequests() called?

Comment: i don't see any new thread/task being created.... i see the .StartNew() but no where do i see it called..

Comment: if this code is all executed using same thread then no blocking would occur.

Comment: Allocation.AllocateOutstandingRequests() is called in several places whenever inventory is changed, for instance, when new inventory is received. The receiving of inventory is handled in another class.

Comment: The thread id is different as per tracing, that's why I'm expecting lock to block.

Comment: not in the code you posted... hard to help when we are missing code.

Comment: i see the function declaration (as i state in my comment) but no where is it called in your post.

Comment: my point is that is where the thread/task is being created.. it's possible that you are not generating enough work to cause a block.

Comment: .NET's TPL is more reluctant to context switch, the cost in doing so is not always worth it based on the tasks it is managing...  you don't really have control of the thread like you do if had invoked via QueueWorkerItem or created a thread yourself.

Comment: now if you generate 300 tasks... maybe it will, but because we can't see how you are running this it's tough to know...

Comment: As can be seen from the logging, the Cancel notification comes in on threadId 42. I expect that thread to block, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: well, i see only 2 logging messages in the AllocateInventory() method.. your logs only have 1 thread (26) running in that lock/block.

Comment: the logs for thread 42 aren't in lock/blocks....  I don't see a problem at all.

Comment: what do you think lock does?

Comment: But Messaging.Cancel runs in thread 42, and makes the call to Allocation.AddCancel, which is where I am expecting the block to occur, and doesn't.

Comment: i see what you are saying...  hmm...

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me.... it should block...

Comment: Welcome to my headache :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locking does block. My unit tests used the wrong data. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.